# Problem with GPS on xiaomi

Tags: applications, gps, gps-tracking

I have a Xiaomi redmi note 3 pro and i have installed an application that control in real time your running (it take the Speed, the course)  thanks to the GPS.
But sometimes the GPS lose the signal and my results are not clear.
There are some settigs to change or the application has a problem?

Comment: All I can say is lower-tier phones tend to have spotty GPS hardware.

Comment: Are you running in an urban environment? Out in the country? Losing a GPS signal can be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps your rom/firmware has a bug with GPS, try to reflash the firmware of the your xiaomi form the official site